# Can you tell me what this plant is

Tags: identification

Hi my first post on here as I've been trying to find out what this purple plant is that popped up from no where. It's in a part of the garden where I lost a stunning old red rose due to weather in winter.
Thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 2):

Purple leafed Amaranthus, way cool weed!

[image: purple leafed Amaranthus]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a member of the mint family - possibly red basil or red variety of perilla.  Both are edible herbs. Not sure though.

If it has a square stem that is characteristic of the mint family. If you crush the leaves and it smells spicy that might also help identify it.

http://www.weedalogue.com/perilla/

https://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/2969

Comment: Thanks both I will try that it grew very quick from no where lol